# TYPO3: How to configure plugin preview in Backend

Tags: typo3, backend, extbase

In the backend I want to display some configurations of the plugin the editor has selected. Like in powermail or news plugin. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd apply the same logic as for a [custom preview of any custom element](https://usetypo3.com/custom-fsc-element.html#c30):

- You can [use PageTS to register a custom Fluid template](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/9.5/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/View/PageLayoutView.php#L2174):

  ```
  // Register preview for a custom content element
  mod.web_layout.tt_content.preview.my_content_element = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Templates/Preview/MyContentElement.html
  // Register preview for a plugin
  mod.web_layout.tt_content.preview.list.myext_myplugin = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Templates/Preview/MyPlugin.html
  ```
- Alternatively you can implement the `tt_content_drawItem` hook:

  ```php
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['tt_content_drawItem']['fluid_styled_slider'] = \Acme\Package\MyPreviewRenderer::class;
  ```

  And then implement this hook:

  ```php
  namespace Acme\Package;

  use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface;

  class MyPreviewRenderer implements PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface
  {
      /**
       * ...
       */
      public function preProcess(PageLayoutView &$parentObject, &$drawItem, &$headerContent, &$itemContent, array &$row)
      {
          // 1. Check $row['CType'] for your content element and $row['list_type'] for your plugin in case of "list"
          // 2. Fill $itemContent with your preview
          // 3. Set $drawItem = false; to prevent rendering of the default preview
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I cannot confirm that the options are working. I think the configuration mentioned above is expecting the CType being the relevant modifier. But in case of a plugin it is the list_type, the CType being always 'list'.

Comment: That's correct, I've added more details about this.

Comment: So for option A, the modification of PageTs, there seems to be no option?

Comment: Another great suggestion, I've added an example for that too. Also I've linked the related source in TYPO3v9.

Comment: At least for Typo3 v10, you have to set `mod.web_layout.tt_content.preview.list = 1` in addition as well, or none of your Fluid previews will work. You have to, because of the core checking if the array `['mod']['web_layout']['tt_content']['preview']['list']` exists. Without this setting, only `['list.']` is set.

Comment: I was partially right. By setting `mod.web_layout.tt_content.preview.list = 1`, all plugins without a preview Fluid file are rendered as an error in the backend. You can prevent this by setting `mod.web_layout.tt_content.preview.list = EXT:` because of the way `GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName()` works. However this feels like a big dirty hack to me ...