# TYPO3: How to create backend view with Standalone. (Custom Content Elements)

Tags: php, html, typo3, backend, typo3-9.x

How can i create a backend view template but as **HTML** for custom content elements.

I know i have to use the Standalone class but i do not know how.

**System**: TYPO3 v9 
**Mode**: Composer Mode
**Target**: Custom Content element

Answer (score 0):

The first steps are described here perfectly: [First steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691663/typo3-how-to-configure-plugin-preview-in-backend/55691831#55691831)

After that you will have to include some classes

```
namespace Vendor\YourExtensionName\Hooks\PageLayoutView;

use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
```

Then you have the following:

```
class MyPreviewRenderer implements PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface
{
    /**
     * Preprocesses the preview rendering of a content element of type "Your CType"
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView $parentObject Calling parent object
     * @param bool $drawItem Whether to draw the item using the default functionality
     * @param string $headerContent Header content
     * @param string $itemContent Item content
     * @param array $row Record row of tt_content
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function preProcess(
        PageLayoutView &$parentObject,
        &$drawItem,
        &$headerContent,
        &$itemContent,
        array &$row
    )
    {

    }
```

**Fetch objects**

In the `preProcess` function we have to first fetch the objects. Do not forget. The `&parentObjects` is mapped to the tt_content table and the `&row` holds the information on the current tt_content entry and not the information of your CType which is saved on `yourTable` table. So we have to create an SQL query to get these information. To do so we have the following:

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('yourTable');
    $foo = $queryBuilder
     ->select('*')
     ->from('yourTable')
     ->where(
         $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('tt_content', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($row['uid'], \PDO::PARAM_INT)),
         $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('hidden', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(0, \PDO::PARAM_INT)),
         $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('deleted', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(0, \PDO::PARAM_INT)),
         )
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();
```

What we did here, is to get all the objects that have a relation with the tt_content's `uid`. Note that the tt_content is a **field** in the **yourTable** which holds the `uid` of the tt_content's table entry.

**Define template**

Now that we have all the objects in hand, we have to define the path to the backend **template**.

```
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
$standaloneView = $objectManager->get(StandaloneView::class);
$templatePath = GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:yourExtension/Resources/Private/Templates/Backend/Backend.html');
```

Now we have to assign the objects to a variable in order to pass them to the fluid template.

```
$standaloneView->setFormat('html');
$standaloneView->setTemplatePathAndFilename($templatePath);
$standaloneView->assignMultiple([
                'foo' => $foo,
                'cTypeTitle' => $parentObject->CType_labels[$row['CType']],
                ]);
```

And finally render the template:

```
$itemContent .= $standaloneView->render();
$drawItem = false;
```

**Additional information:**

It is recommended, that you wrap all your code (inside the `preProcess` function) in the CType that it belongs to. To do so you ll have to wrap it like this:

```
if ($row['CType'] === 'yourCTypeName')  {
    //...
}
```